# How to load into Log4j2.xml value of spring.application.name from yaml file

Tags: spring, boot

I need to load to log4j2.xml on start period value of spring.application.name
How to load to log4j2.xml in Spring Boot value for property "serviceName" from application.yaml of spring:application:name

${bundle:application:spring:application:name}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log application name in log4j2 by fetching name from bootstrap.yml in spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60915903/how-to-log-application-name-in-log4j2-by-fetching-name-from-bootstrap-yml-in-spr)